# HTML form not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a form that checks whether or not an email address is valid and outputs VALID or INVALID accordingly. My problem is that it does not work in internet explorer, and this is incredibly frustrating. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Email Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form onSubmit='validate(); return false;'>
        <p>Enter an email address:</p>
        <input id='email' placeholder="example@example.com" size="21" />
        <button type='submit' id='validate'>Submit</button>
        <button type='reset' value='reset'>Reset</button>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <h2 id='result'></h2>
    <script>
        function validateEmail(email) { 
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        }
        function validate(){
            $("#result").text("");
            var email = $("#email").val();
            if (validateEmail(email)) {
                $("#result").text(email + " is valid");
                $("#result").css("color", "green");
            } else {
                $("#result").text(email + " is not valid");
                $("#result").css("color", "red");
            }
            return false;
        }
        $("form").bind("submit", validate);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please be specific instead of saying "does not work". Do you mean validate is never called? It always fails? No output? The entire page turns into a pile of kittens?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?¿ Also your code doesnt look ok, so I'm going to send you a proper answer below.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: and can you specific what version of ie are you getting the error.

Comment: The last version of jQuery is not compatible with lower version of IE9. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @JuaRoAl yep you are right.

Answer (score 1):

First your script tag is wrong

```
<script class="jsbin" src="http:ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
                           ^^^^^^
```

it is missing the `//`

---

You are calling validate in TWO places.

```
<form onSubmit='validate(); return false;'>
```

and

```
$("form").bind("submit", validate);
```

There should only be one. Get rid on the inline one and stick with the bind one.

---

Also, older IEs can tend to have an issue with method names and ids being the same. So change the id of the validate button to `id="btnValidate"` and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ctw44q9w/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function validateEmail(email) { 
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }

    function validate(email){
        $("#result").text("");
        if (validateEmail(email)) {
            $("#result").text(email + " is valid");
            $("#result").css("color", "green");
        } else {
            $("#result").text(email + " is not valid");
            $("#result").css("color", "red");
        }
     }

    $('#validate').on('click', function(){
        validate($('#email').val());
    });
});


<p>Enter an email address:</p>
<input id='email' placeholder="example@example.com" size="21">
    <button type='submit' id='validate'>Submit</button>
    <button type='reset' value='reset'>Reset</button>

    <br/>
<h2 id='result'></h2>
```

Also I have removed the `onclick()` (it´s a bad practice) and I set by `on()` jquery. It´s very important the jquery version you are using(`1.11.2` should be ok), so make sure the one you are using is compatible with IE.

I recomend you use this to get everithing working on the IE

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Note: Set for the version you need.

I hope it´s helps.